# How to scrape XML with Python?

Tags: python, xml, dom, scrape

I am trying to parse the following XML with Python. I am using:

```
thumbnail_tag = dom.getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')[0].toxml()
```

This selects the first one. I know I can change the `[0]` to `[1]` to get the tag with `yt:name="mqdefault"`, but is there another way to change the parameter in the statement above (add something to `media:thumbnail`)?

```
<entry>
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/default.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:01:48.500" yt:name="default" />
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/mqdefault.jpg" height="180" width="320" yt:name="mqdefault" />
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/hqdefault.jpg" height="360" width="480" yt:name="hqdefault" />
</entry>

<entry>
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/default.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:01:48.500" yt:name="default" />
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/mqdefault.jpg" height="180" width="320" yt:name="mqdefault" />
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/hqdefault.jpg" height="360" width="480" yt:name="hqdefault" />
</entry>
```

Comment: This is not XML because a root element is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a dom object of this xml string you have to define **XML Namespaces** in the root tag or in the same tag.

The Namespace is defined by the **xmlns attribute** in the start of an element.

The namespace declaration has the following syntax:

```
xmlns:prefix="URI"
```

**For Example:**

```
<root>
    <h:table xmlns:h="http://bluejson.com/W3C/">
        <h:tr>
            <h:td>JSON</h:td>
            <h:td>JavaScript</h:td>
            <h:td>Python</h:td>
        </h:tr>
    </h:table>

    <f:table xmlns:f="http://bluejson.com/W3C/">
        <f:name>My Study Room</f:name>
        <f:width>800</f:width>
        <f:height>420</f:height>
        <f:length>1120</f:length>
    </f:table>
</root>
```

In the example above, the xmlns attribute in the  tag give the h: and f: prefixes a qualified namespace.

When a namespace is defined for an element, all child elements with the same prefix are associated with the same namespace.

Namespaces can be declared in the elements where they are used or in the XML root element:

```
<root xmlns:h="http://bluejson.com/W3C/" xmlns:f="http://bluejson.com/W3C/">
    <h:table>
        <h:tr>
            <h:td>JSON</h:td>
            <h:td>JavaScript</h:td>
            <h:td>Python</h:td>
        </h:tr>
    </h:table>

    <f:table>
        <f:name>My Study Room</f:name>
        <f:width>800</f:width>
        <f:height>420</f:height>
        <f:length>1120</f:length>
    </f:table>
</root>
```

**Now, The Python code to create you xml dom Object and get attributes**

```
import xml.dom.minidom

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString("""
<root xmlns:media="http://media/" xmlns:yt="http://media/yt/">
    <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/default.jpg" height="90" width="120" time="00:01:48.500" yt:name="default" />
    <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/mqdefault.jpg" height="180" width="320" yt:name="mqdefault" />
    <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/hqdefault.jpg" height="360" width="480" yt:name="hqdefault" />
</root>""")

media_thumbnail = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://media/","thumbnail")
print media_thumbnail[0].getAttribute("height")
print media_thumbnail[0].getAttribute("width")
print media_thumbnail[0].getAttribute("time")
print media_thumbnail[0].getAttributeNS("http://media/yt/","name")
media_thumbnail[0].setAttribute("unit","px")
media_thumbnail[0].setAttributeNS("http://media/yt/","value","1")
print dom.toxml()
```

Output:

```
90
120
00:01:48.500
default
<?xml version="1.0" ?><root xmlns:media="http://media/" xmlns:yt="http://media/yt/">
    <media:thumbnail height="90" time="00:01:48.500" unit="px" url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/default.jpg" value="1" width="120" yt:name="default"/>
    <media:thumbnail height="180" url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/mqdefault.jpg" width="320" yt:name="mqdefault"/>
    <media:thumbnail height="360" url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k8J-72MmTGg/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" yt:name="hqdefault"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is documentation on python XML parsers.](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html)

For your implementation you can use:

```
for element in thumbnail_tag:
    attr = element.getAttribute('yt:name')
```

To change the value of the attribute:

```
for element in thumbnail_tag:
    attr = element.getAttribute('yt:name')
    if attr == 'mqdefault':
        element.setAttribute('yt:name', 'new_value')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the standard `xml.etree.ElementTree` instead of the DOM. While DOM is more traditional, it is also more uggly and more difficult to use. Have a look at [Dive Into Python 3, Chapter 12. XML](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/xml.html).

The standard module support a subset of the XPath language that may be usefull in your case.

Here is the sample code that extracts the wanted elements from the `sample.xml`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('sample.xml')

root = tree.getroot()     # the root element of the tree

##et.dump(root)             # here is how the input file looks inside

print '==========================================='
print 'Iterate through all media:thumbnail:'

# XPath expressions that describe the wanted elements. Here we have 3 ones;
# however, they are just strings and can be constructed on the fly.
xp_default = ".//{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail[" \
                 "@{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}name='default']"

xp_mqdefault = ".//{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail[" \
                 "@{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}name='mqdefault']"

xp_hqdefault = ".//{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail[" \
                 "@{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}name='hqdefault']"

for e in root.iterfind(xp_default):
    et.dump(e)
    print '-------------------------------------------'

for e in root.iterfind(xp_mqdefault):
    et.dump(e)
    print '-------------------------------------------'

for e in root.iterfind(xp_hqdefault):
    et.dump(e)
    print '-------------------------------------------'
    print 'The e.attrib is a dictionary of attributes:'
    print e.attrib
```

It prints the following...:

```
c:\tmp\___python\sharataka\so12776774>py a.py
===========================================
Iterate through all media:thumbnail:
<ns0:thumbnail xmlns:ns0="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:ns1="http://gdata
.youtube.com/schemas/2007" height="90" time="00:01:41" url="http://img.youtube.c
om/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/default.jpg" width="120" ns1:name="default" />

-------------------------------------------
<ns0:thumbnail xmlns:ns0="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:ns1="http://gdata
.youtube.com/schemas/2007" height="180" url="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYc
Js/mqdefault.jpg" width="320" ns1:name="mqdefault" />

-------------------------------------------
<ns0:thumbnail xmlns:ns0="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:ns1="http://gdata
.youtube.com/schemas/2007" height="360" url="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYc
Js/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" ns1:name="hqdefault" />

-------------------------------------------
The e.attrib is a dictionary of attributes:
{'url': 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/hqdefault.jpg', 'width': '480', '
height': '360', '{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}name': 'hqdefault'}
```

... for the `sample.xml` (found somewhere, shortened) with the content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
  xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
  xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
  <entry>
    <media:group>
      <media:title type='plain'>Learning the ABCs</media:title>
      <media:description type='plain'>
        A great method for teaching kids the alphabet.
      </media:description>
      <media:keywords>alphabet, teaching, children</media:keywords>
      <yt:duration seconds='202'/>
      <yt:videoid>jXE6G9CYcJs</yt:videoid>
      <media:credit role='uploader' scheme='urn:youtube'
          yt:display='GoogleDeveloperssFriend'>GoogleDeveloperssFriend</media:credit>
      <media:category label='Education'
        scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>
        Education</media:category>
      <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/jXE6G9CYcJs'
        type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true'
        expression='full' duration='202' yt:format='5'/>
      <media:content
        url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENySANFEgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
        type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full'
        duration='202' yt:format='1'/>
      <media:content
        url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENySARFEgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
        type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full'
        duration='202' yt:format='6'/>
      <media:player url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXE6G9CYcJs'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/default.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:01:41' yt:name='default'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/hqdefault.jpg'
        height='360' width='480' yt:name='hqdefault'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/mqdefault.jpg'
        height='180' width='320' yt:name='mqdefault'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/1.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:00:50.500' yt:name='start'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/2.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:01:41' yt:name='end'/>
      <media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/3.jpg'
        height='90' width='120' time='00:02:31.500' yt:name='middle'/>
    </media:group>
    <yt:statistics viewCount='286355' favoriteCount='201'/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```